# Python. Tkinter. Выпадающий список в Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, выпадающий-список

Есть `Canvas`, элементы в котором отсортированы по столбцам и строкам. Пример:

```
test_lab = Label(self, text="Test label: ")
test_lab .grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
test_btn = Button(self, text="Test btn", width=8, command=lambda: print('click'))
```

Хочу внедрить в очередную строку выпадающий список вместо кнопки, как в примере выше, но получаю ошибку. По итогу методом `.grid` упаковать не получается. Знаю, есть много кода в методичках и на сайтах разных, но там в основном встречается код формата **"Создание главного окна --> Создание списка --> Упаковка через `.pack`"**, но мне это не подходит, тк у меня создание виджетов происходит не в основном методе, а там все примеры идут с root и тд. Что можете посоветовать? Формат моего кода таков:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В `main` создаю `root = Tk()`, а далее перехожу в класс `test2 = Test2(root)` (название приведено к к примеру). Далее в этом классе создается UI через функцию `setUI(self)`. В ней то я и пытаюсь создать список по примеру выше.